# Autowire List of Object setting empty list

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm trying to use @Autowired in a List to my bean class. Seems, Spring is setting empty list.

Here is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
 public class CommonConfig { 
     @Bean
     public List<Pattern> support() {
          List<Pattern> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
          // Business logic
          return urlPatterns ;
    }
    return urlPatterns;
  }
}
```

And the Bean class is as follow:

```
@Component 
public class Support {
    //@Resource(name="auditServices")
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("support")
    private List<Pattern> auditServicesMap = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
}
```

The problem is - I found the list is empty but during the Bean creation I see that the is not empty. If you Autowire that list using a Wrapper class seems working good. Any help appreciated.

Comment: could you please try to add @Configuration to Support class ? And I think you can remove @Qualifier("support").

Comment: But, CommonConfig is my @Configuration class. And Support is the Bean class.

Comment: sorry don't add @Configuration to Support class. Just remove @Qualifier("support") and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize the `auditServicesMap` in the `Support` class.
Bean is getting created properly that is non-empty but after the bean injection, you're initializing the `auditServicesMap` to an empty `ArrayList<Pattern>` again. The bean should be injected like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("support")
private List<Pattern> auditServicesMap;
```

Comment: Well, I changed to setter method but didn't work



  @Autowired
  public void setAuditServicesMap(List<Pattern> auditServicesMap) {
  this.auditServicesMap = auditServicesMap;
 }

Comment: Try @Resource(name="support") and keep the autowire as it is. Do not move in any setter method.

Comment: Unfortunately adding @Resource annotation doesn't help me